# Is there a resource for all of the custom GUI styles that come with Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Looking in some other Editor Window scripts I see GUI Styles like `"OL Title"` and `"OL Minus"`. I'd like to have a resource that shows all styles that we have access to (and bonus if it describes/shows what they look like). I assume it exists *somewhere* otherwise how would the developer of those scripts know they exist? I just can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Asking on the [Unity forum](https://forum.unity3d.com/) might be better than on here. Stack Overflow is not the place for this sort of question.

Comment: Interesting opinion. There must be some hidden description of what sort of questions this is the place for. I assumed it was just general programming questions. Neither the homepage nor the ask question form say anything otherwise. I'm obviously not new to stack overflow.

Comment: Regarding the forum, it has already been asked without answer here https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/helpwhats-the-ol-box.199091/ so I decided to ask it here where generally people are better at answering the question asked.

Comment: There's a specific "Close" option for closing questions where software recommendations are requested. It's simply out of scope for stack overflow intended users.

Comment: I'm not surprised that the topic hasn't had as much interest as it could have, on the Unity Forum, many of the forum users seem to be beginners themselves, rather than experienced knowledge sharers.

Comment: Try also https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ for more specific target audience, and word your question as a request "how do I do this" rather than "recommend this". Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Unity doesn't provide any documentation on that.

BTW, [Here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/792118/what-are-the-editor-resources-by-name-for-editorgu.html) is a collection of editor resource names.

Comment: That's rather unfortunate. Their editor scripting system is amazing. I just wish they had better documentation of all that they have available. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to use GUIStyle constructor -

```
GUIStyle mystyle = new GUIStyle("some style element");
```

And a list of style elements -

```
"ToolbarButton"
"CN Box"
"Button"
"CN EntryBackEven"
"Toolbar"
"CN EntryInfo"
"CN EntryBackodd"
"CN StatusWarn"
"CN StatusError"
"Box"
"CN StatusInfo"
"CN CountBadge"
"MiniButtonMiddle"
"MiniButton"
"MiniButtonLeft"
"ErrorStyle"
"MiniButtonRight"
"LogStyle"
"CN Message"
"WarningStyle"
"MessageStyle"
"EvenBackground"
"OddBackground"
"StatusError"
"ObjectPickerResultsGrid"
"PR Label"
"ProjectBrowserGridLabel"
"ProjectBrowserHeaderBgMiddle"
"ProjectBrowserSubAssetExpandBtn"
"toolbarDropDown"
"ToolbarSeachTextField"
"SearchCancelButtonEmpty"
"ToolbarSeachCancelButton"
"SearchTextField"
"ObjectPickerBackground"
"ObjectPickerPreviewBackground"
"Foldout"
"ProjectBrowserHeaderBgTop"
"NotificationBackground"
"ObjectPickerToolbar"
"PR Ping"
"PR TextField"
"ProjectBrowserIconDropShadow"
"ProjectBrowserPreviewBg"
"CN EntryError"
"ProjectBrowserTextureIconDropShadow"
"ProjectBrowserSubAssetBg"
"ProjectBrowserSubAssetBgOpenEnded"
"WhiteLabel"
"CountBadge"
"StatusWarn"
"ProjectBrowserSubAssetBgDivider"
"In BigTitle"
"StatusLog"
"WhiteMiniLabel"
"LargeLabel"
"BoldLabel"
"ColorPickerBox"
"ProjectBrowserSubAssetBgCloseEnded"
"ProjectBrowserSubAssetBgMiddle"
"WordWrappedLabel"
"CN EntryWarn"
"MiniBoldLabel"
"MiniTextField"
"WhiteLargeLabel"
"WhiteBoldLabel"
"miniButton"
"miniButtonLeft"
"WordWrappedMiniLabel"
"miniButtonRight"
"Radio"
"toolbarPopup"
"toolbarTextField"
"miniButtonMid"
"ToolbarSeachCancelButtonEmpty"
"ToolbarSeachTextFieldPopup"
"SearchCancelButton"
"HelpBox"
"AssetLabel Partial"
"MinMaxHorizontalSliderThumb"
"AssetLabel Icon"
"ProjectBrowserIconAreaBg"
"selectionRect"
"AssetLabel"
"Label"
"BoldLabel"
"DropDownButton"
"MiniLabel"
"FoldoutPreDrop"
"ProgressBarBack"
"ProgressBarBar"
"ProgressBarText"
"Tooltip"
"IN Title"
"MiniBoldLabel"
"BoldToggle"
"textField"
"IN TitleText"
"Foldout"
"NotificationText"
"ControlLabel"
"ToggleMixed"
"ObjectField"
"ObjectFieldThumb"
"MiniPopup"
"ObjectFieldMiniThumb"
"TextFieldDropDownText"
"Toggle"
"ColorField"
"TextFieldDropDown"
```

The list might not be complete. Please add if you find any missing style element.

Comment: Thank you for the list. That's a start!